# removing substring from main string with c

Tags: c, string, visual-studio

I need to remove substring `"hello"` from the mains string and now I have already replaced `'x'` with `'ks'` and `'z'` with `'ts'` as my assignment asked my to do. But now I can't think of a way to remove substrings `"hello"` and I've tried that with `memmove()` but after that the printf prints `"(null)"`.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void antikorso(char *dest, const char *src) {
    const char *p = src;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; *p != '\0'; i++, p++)
    {
        if (*p == 'x') {
            dest[i++] = 'k';
            dest[i] = 's';
        }
        else if (*p == 'z') {
            dest[i++] = 't';
            dest[i] = 's';
        }
        else
        {
            dest[i] = *p;
        }
    }

    dest[i] = '\0';
    printf("\n%s", dest);
    char c[10] = "hello";
    int j;
    while (dest = strstr(dest, c))
        memmove(dest, dest + strlen(c), 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(c)));

    printf("\n%s", dest);
}


int main(void)
{

     const char *lol = "yxi izexeen hello asd hello asd";
     char asd[1000];
     antikorso(asd, lol);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a logic error on your side. It prints `NULL` because after you've removed `"hello"`, the condition in the
`while` loop gets evaluated again and this leads to:

```
dest = strstr(dest, c);
```

which eventually will assign `NULL` to `dest`, which is what you print. You need
another variable to remember the original string.

```
char *original = dest;
char c[10] = "hello";
while (dest = strstr(dest, c))
    memmove(dest, dest + strlen(c), 1 + strlen(dest + strlen(c)));

printf("\n%s", original);
```

This will print you line without `"hello"`s.

Comment: This way it will print "yksii itsekseen   asd   asd" and the right one is "yksi itsekseen asd asd" like it will leave a whitespace to the point where we remove hello and yea this could be fixed by deciding that the  c starts with whitespace like this c[10] = " hello" but if the automatic checker puts there string which starts with "hello" I am screwed cause there's no whitespace before that

Comment: @michael Your algorithm removes only the substrings `"hello"`, it doesn't know about words. If you want to remove the substring in the middle of a word and the white spaces when the substring is a word, then you have to modify your algorithm. Hint: when `strstr` returns the location of a substring, look at the character before and after the substring. If the character before the substring is a white space, then the destination of `memmove` should be `dest-1` and you would have to adjust the number of bytes to be moved...

Comment: @michael If the character after the substring is a white space, you would have to adjust the number if bytes to be moved as well. There are 2 special cases: when the substring is the beginning and when the substring is at the end. Let me know if you are able to modify your original code, if not post a comment and I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: I got it modified!